# the function of "it" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He's made **it** an imprisonable offense **to connect this house to Floo Network, place a Portkey here, or Apparate in or out**. (From Harry Potter)

Does the meaning of **it** derive from **to connect this house to Floo Network, place a Portkey here, or Apparate in or out**?

And does the sentence mean that:
connecting this house to Floo Network, placing a Portkey here, or Apparating in or out are imprisonable offenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *He's made it an imprisonable offense to connect this house to Floo*
>   *Network, place a Portkey here, or Apparate in or out.*

No: in object extraposition the "it" is a dummy element serving as object and the subordinate clause as extraposed object.

The ‘basic’ non-extraposed version is inadmissible by vitue of having the subordinate clause located between the verb and another complement (* *He’s made to connect this* *house to Floo Network, place a Portkey here, or Apparate in or out an imprisonable* *offence*.)

Answer (score 2):

You got the meaning of the sentence right. "It" is a pronoun, this allows to say:

> It is an imprisonable offense to ....

so the statement / conclusion is at the front, before the examples. It is easier to understand when written this way, you just have to read "it" as a referent, and fill in the later instances.

Comment: I'm not certain if this is accurate. It seems more likely to me that *it* is a [dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) in the same sense as ***it*** *is raining* (or as in the first word of this sentence). I don't think its referent is the subsequent phrase, but that it's simply there for grammatical coherence.